# Storing and Retrieving ArrayList values from hashmap

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have a hashmap of the following type

```
HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>> map=new HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>>();
```

The values stored are like this :

```
mango | 0,4,8,9,12
apple | 2,3
grapes| 1,7
peach | 5,6,11
```

I want to store as well as fetch those Integers using Iterator or any other way with minimum lines of code.How can I do it?

**EDIT 1**

The numbers are added at random (not together) as key is matched to the appropriate line.

**EDIT 2**

How can I point to the arraylist while adding ?

I am getting error while adding a new number `18` in the line `map.put(string,number);`

Answer (score 60):

Our variable:

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
```

To store:

```
map.put("mango", new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(0, 4, 8, 9, 12)));
```

To add numbers one and one, you can do something like this:

```
String key = "mango";
int number = 42;
if (map.get(key) == null) {
    map.put(key, new ArrayList<Integer>());
}
map.get(key).add(number);
```

In Java 8 you can use `putIfAbsent` to add the list if it did not exist already:

```
map.putIfAbsent(key, new ArrayList<Integer>());
map.get(key).add(number);
```

---

Use the `map.entrySet()` method to iterate on:

```
for (Entry<String, List<Integer>> ee : map.entrySet()) {
    String key = ee.getKey();
    List<Integer> values = ee.getValue();
    // TODO: Do something.
}
```

Comment: :What does `ee.getValue()` return ?An ArrayList I suppose.So i need a temporary arralist I suppose.Is that so?

Comment: @InsaneCoder Yes, it returns an ArrayList (of Integers). Whether or not you need a temporary ArrayList or not depends on what you want to do with it. You can call ee.getValue multiple times and still get the same ArrayList.

Answer (score 3):

The modern way (as of 2020) to add entries to a multimap (a map of lists) in Java is:

```
map.computeIfAbsent("apple", k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(2);
map.computeIfAbsent("apple", k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(3);
```

According to [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) docs:

> If the specified key is not already associated with a value (or is mapped to `null`), attempts to compute its value using the given mapping function and enters it into this map unless `null`.
>
> Returns:
> `the current (existing or computed) value associated with the specified key, or null if the computed value is null`

The most idiomatic way to iterate a map of lists is using [`Map.forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#forEach-java.util.function.BiConsumer-) and [`Iterable.forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html#forEach-java.util.function.Consumer-):

```
map.forEach((k, l) -> l.forEach(v -> /* use k and v here */));
```

Or, as shown in other answers, a traditional `for` loop:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> e : map.entrySet()) {
    String k = e.getKey();
    for (Integer v : e.getValue()) {
        /* use k and v here */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Iterator it = map.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
     Map.Entry pairs = (Map.Entry)it.next();

     if(pairs.getKey().equals("mango"))
     {
        map.put(pairs.getKey(), pairs.getValue().add(18));
     }

     else if(!map.containsKey("mango"))
     {
        List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ints.add(18);
        map.put("mango",ints);
     }

     it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
}
```

EDIT:
So inside the while try this:

```
map.put(pairs.getKey(), pairs.getValue().add(number))
```

You are getting the error because you are trying to put an integer to the values, whereas it is expected an `ArrayList`.

EDIT 2:
Then put the following inside your while loop:

```
if(pairs.getKey().equals("mango"))
{
    map.put(pairs.getKey(), pairs.getValue().add(18));
}

else if(!map.containsKey("mango"))
{
     List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
     ints.add(18);
     map.put("mango",ints);
 }
```

EDIT 3:
By reading your requirements, I come to think you may not need a loop. You may want to only check if the map contains the key `mango`, and if it does add `18`, else create a new entry in the map with key `mango` and value `18`.

So all you may need is the following, without the loop:

```
if(map.containsKey("mango"))
{
    map.put("mango", map.get("mango).add(18));
}

else
{
    List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ints.add(18);
    map.put("mango", ints);
}
```

Comment: How would I add an integer to a particular key.I am getting error in `map.put(string,number);` while adding.

Comment: I Haven't got an IDE to test the code in, so there could be a syntax error.

Comment: OK !! I will check.Please post it

Comment: :Actually I want something that "If there is a key 'mango' add 18 to it otherwise create the key 'mango' and add 18 to it".I think this code will not do it

Comment: @InsaneCoder Please see EDIT 2

Comment: @InsaneCoder and EDIT 3

Answer (score 2):

You can use like this(Though the random number generator logic is not upto the mark)

```
public class WorkSheet {
    HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String,ArrayList<Integer>>();

public static void main(String args[]) {
    WorkSheet test = new WorkSheet();
    test.inputData("mango", 5);
    test.inputData("apple", 2);
    test.inputData("grapes", 2);
    test.inputData("peach", 3);
    test.displayData();

}
public void displayData(){
    for (Entry<String, ArrayList<Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        System.out.print(entry.getKey()+" | ");
        for(int fruitNo : entry.getValue()){
            System.out.print(fruitNo+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
public void inputData(String name ,int number) {
    Random rndData = new Random();
    ArrayList<Integer> fruit = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for(int i=0 ; i<number ; i++){
        fruit.add(rndData.nextInt(10));
    }
    map.put(name, fruit);
}
}
```

### OUTPUT

```
grapes | 7 5 
apple | 9 5 
peach | 5 5 8 
mango | 4 7 1 5 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try using MultiMap instead of HashMap

Initialising it will require fewer lines of codes. Adding and retrieving the values will also make it shorter.

```
Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
```

would become:

```
Multimap<String, Integer> multiMap = ArrayListMultimap.create();
```

You can check this link: http://java.dzone.com/articles/hashmap-%E2%80%93-single-key-and

Answer (score 1):

Method1 : Use putIfAbsent

```
    Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap();
    map.putIfAbsent("mango",new ArrayList<>());
    map.get("mango").add(5);
```

Method 2: Check key present in Map

```
    Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap();
    if(! map.containsKey("mango"){
          map.put("mango",new ArrayList<>());
    }
    List<Integer> list = map.get("mango");
    list.add(3);
```

Method 3: Use getOrDefault

```
    Map<String, List<Integer>> map = new HashMap();
    List<Integer> list = map.getOrDefault("mango",new ArrayList<>());
    list.add(4)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
 System.out.println( entry.getKey());     
 System.out.println( entry.getValue());//Returns the list of values
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
static HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> has(int arr[], int target) {
    HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> hm = new HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>();
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (!hm.containsKey(arr[i])) {
            ArrayList<Integer> res = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            res.add(i + 1);
            hm.put(arr[i], res);
        } else {
            hm.get(arr[i]).add(i);
        }
    }
    return hm;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Fetch all at once =

```
List<Integer> list = null;

if(map!= null) 
{ 
  list = new ArrayList<Integer>(map.values()); 
}
```

For Storing =

```
if(map!= null) 
{ 
  list = map.get(keyString); 
   if(list == null)
    {
         list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    }
  list.add(value);
  map.put(keyString,list);
}
```